# Number of children in DOM Document

Tags: html, xml, dom

This question is somehow theoretical.
My teacher is explaining us the theory behind DOM Documents. Now he is teaching us that in this example:

```
<span>
    <p>Test</p>{CR}
    {CR}
    <p>Test2</p>
</span>
```

The tag span has 4 children. The 2 < p>'s and the 2 Carriage Return. Is that right? Can you provide me with some official sources?

Comment: Node types: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType and nodes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node

Comment: Did you nicely format this, or is there, technically, also a carriage return after `<span>` and the second `</p>`? Anyway, I think your teacher is referring to the various types of nodes in the DOM. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227416/specification-document-dom-text-nodes

Comment: I've formatted this =)
So the {CR} is part of a node kind. Ty for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementation specific. Some parsers convert the CR into a textnode containing the CR character and some parsers ignore it.

In compliant browsers it's

`span.childNodes === [Text("/n"), <p>Text</p>, Text("\n\n"), <p>test2</p>]`

Answer (score 0):

I Think {CR} is content of tag span , because {CR} is not tag so it is not node and it is not child :).